# Is it possible to intiailize variables in a constructor for a Laravel facade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I am creating a custom facade and want to have certain variables initialized at every instance of using `customFacade::doSomething()`, is that possible? My main purpose for doing this is to be able to store variables that are other objects and call functions on them directly. Example being `customFacade::client->send()` where in this case `client` is the initialized variable of an object with a `send()` function. I am aware I can have a function `client()` instead and return the a new instance of the object so the `send()` goes through, but I'd still like to know if its possible the other way.

In a normal class I can do below, but it doesn't work on facades.

```
$protected client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new instanceOfObject();
}
```

Comment: so what is the underlying class, instance, this facade is a proxy for in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Since a Facade uses static functions you could only do something like

```
public static $client = null;

public static function init() {
    if(self::$client == null)
        self::$client = new instanceOfObject();
}

// somewhere else
customFacade::init();
customFacade::client->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will resolve all the dependencies you need out of the service container, in the class constructor which underlies your facade. A toy example to show my point, will have `UserRepository` resolved in the `DateService`, and therefore the `Dates` facade.

Usage like,

```
    return view('profile' => [
        ...
        'time' => Dates::loggedLocal(),
        ...
    ]);
```

DatetimeService.php

```
class DatetimeService
{
    private $userRepository;
    
    public function __construct(
        UserRepository $userRepository
    ) {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Get the logged in users local time
     *
     * @return Carbon
     */
    public function loggedLocal() : Carbon
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->current();
        return Carbon::now()->setTimezone($user->timezone);
    }
```

Dates.php

```
class Dates extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'date-service'; }
}
```

DateServiceProvider.php

```
class DateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('date-service', function()
        {
            return new DateTimeService;
        });
    }
}
```